# Nested Iteration for separate

Tags: java, oop, nullpointerexception, linked-list, comparator

I have 2 lists-

[(Tandoor, Indian), (Biryani, Indian), (Pizza, Italian)]

{ in the above, left item is a food item of cuisine type on right}

and

[(John, Indian), (Mary, Indian), (Sam, Italian)]

{ in the above, left person has choice of cuisine type on right}

I need to print out the contents of the lists as
John Tandoor
John Biryani
Mary Tandoor
Mary Biryani
Sam Pizza

The APIs for initializing the 2 given lists, printing the output and handling Pair objects (comparing, accessing key and value) are given.

Why am I getting nullpointerexception in the following -

```
package a1;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    static class Pair implements Comparable<Pair>{
        String pairKey;
        String pairValue;

        Pair(String pairKey, String pairValue) {
            this.pairKey = pairKey;
            this.pairValue = pairValue;
        }

        public String getPairKey() {
            return pairKey;
        }

        public String getPairValue() {
            return pairValue;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return getPairKey() + " " + getPairValue();
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Pair pair) {
            int compare = pairKey.compareTo(pair.getPairKey());
            if(compare == 0) {
                compare = pairValue.compareTo(pair.getPairValue());
            }
            return compare;
        }
    }
    static List<Pair> solve(List<Pair> lunchMenuPairs, List<Pair> teamCuisinePreferencePairs){
        List<Pair> result= null;
        for(Pair first : teamCuisinePreferencePairs){
            for(Pair name : lunchMenuPairs)
            {
                String a1 = first.getPairValue();
                String a2 = name.getPairValue();
                String a3 = first.getPairKey();
                String a4 = name.getPairKey();
                if(first.compareTo(name)==0)
                {
                    System.out.println(a3);
                    System.out.println(a4);
                    Pair pair = new Pair(a3,a4);
                    result.add(pair);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void readAndSetParameters(List<Pair> lunchMenuPairs, List<Pair> teamCuisinePreferencePairs) {
        int lunchMenuPairCount = -1;
        int teamCuisinePreferencePairCount = -1;

        String tempOption = null, tempOptionValue = null;;
        try(Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            lunchMenuPairCount = in.nextInt();
            while(lunchMenuPairCount > 0) {
                lunchMenuPairCount--;

                tempOption = in.next();
                tempOptionValue = in.next();
                Pair pair = new Pair(tempOption, tempOptionValue);
                lunchMenuPairs.add(pair);
            }

            teamCuisinePreferencePairCount = in.nextInt();
            while(teamCuisinePreferencePairCount > 0) {
                teamCuisinePreferencePairCount--;

                tempOption = in.next();
                tempOptionValue = in.next();
                Pair pair = new Pair(tempOption, tempOptionValue);
                teamCuisinePreferencePairs.add(pair);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void print(List<?> resultPairs) {
        for (Object pair : resultPairs) {
            System.out.println(pair);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Pair> lunchMenuPairs = new LinkedList<>();
        List<Pair> teamCuisinePreferencePairs = new LinkedList<>();
        readAndSetParameters(lunchMenuPairs, teamCuisinePreferencePairs);
        List<Pair> result = solve( lunchMenuPairs, teamCuisinePreferencePairs );
        Collections.sort(result);
        print(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: What line causes the NPE? Use a debugger and set a break point to figure out the problem.

Comment: Don't know. *Where* are you getting NullPointerException?

Comment: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/5221149)

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5221149)

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). E.g. this means to change the code to run with specific values that cause the problem, rather than asking user for input, especially since you haven't shown how the input should be provided, in to cause the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
static List<Pair> solve(List<Pair> lunchMenuPairs, List<Pair> teamCuisinePreferencePairs){
    List<Pair> result= null;
    ...
```

to

```
static List<Pair> solve(List<Pair> lunchMenuPairs, List<Pair> teamCuisinePreferencePairs){
    List<Pair> result= new ArrayList<>();
    ...
```

Comment: Console-3
John
Indian
Mary
Indian
Sam
Italian
3
Tandoor
Indian
Biryani
Indian
Pizza
Italian
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:141)
 at a1.main.main(main.java:99)